# python understanding **kwargs

Tags: python, keyword-argument

I am trying to understand **kwargs. For the last part below, I would like to run the function over each value from `tuple a and b`. I was expecting output `4 and 6`. What am I missing? How should I change my code so that the function `summation` runs over each value from `tuples a and b`?

```
#understanding **
def summation(a,b):
    return (a+b)

print (summation(2,3))

dic2={'a':8,'b':9}
print(summation(**dic2))

dic1={'a':(1),'b':(3)}
print(summation(**dic1))

dic3={'a':(1,2),'b':(3,4)}
print(summation(**dic3))


5
17
4
(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Comment: Just write a loop? BTW: You don't have a tuple there but a list. Check what `type(([1,2]))` gives you.

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with kwargs. You just need that checks the types of a and b and does something different depending on the input type. And note that there are no Tuples in sight, only dicts and arrays, (1) is just 1, only (1,) is actually a tuple.

Comment: i am trying to understand kwargs and dont want to write a loop. I have modified my question to show tuples

Comment: This has nothing to do with kwargs anc whatever you want to achieve cannot be magically achieved with kwargs.

Comment: the problem is that your function has a fixed amount of parameters, instead **kwargs fit well when you don't care about the amounts

Comment: `tuple(x+y for x,y in zip(a,b))` will basically achieve what you want and guess what ... that comprehension is basically a loop.

Answer (score 0):

`**kwargs` has the result of unpacking your `dict` into the named function arguments, so let's look at what each of your examples does:

```
dic2={'a':8,'b':9}
print(summation(**dic2))
```

Here, the 8 is passed as a, and 9 as b, so the function returns 8+9

```
dic1={'a':(1),'b':(3)}
print(summation(**dic1))
```

Here, 1 (note, NOT the tuple containing 1, which would be `(1,)`) is passed as a and 3 as be, so the function returns 1+3

```
dic3={'a':(1,2),'b':(3,4)}
print(summation(**dic3))
```

Here the tuple (1,2) is passed as and (3,4) as b, so the function returns `(1,2)+(3,4)`, which in python 'adding' tuples concatenates them.

In your case, if you want to do element-wise addition of tuples, you will either need to loop through the elements yourself, or use a fancy built-in method to do the looping for you, consider `zip`. Here's an example for you:

```py
def summation_elementwise(a,b):
    try:
        # loop through and add elementwise if iterable
        return tuple( aa+bb for aa,bb in zip(a,b) )
    except TypeError:
        # just add if not iterable
        return a+b

print (summation_elementwise(2,3))

dic2={'a':8,'b':9}
print(summation_elementwise(**dic2))

dic1={'a':(1),'b':(3)}
print(summation_elementwise(**dic1))

dic1={'a':(1,),'b':(3,)}
print(summation_elementwise(**dic1))

dic3={'a':(1,2),'b':(3,4)}
print(summation_elementwise(**dic3))


5
17
4
(4,)
(4, 6)
```

Comment: Catching a type error is a terrible practice. Perform proper instance checks instead.

Comment: Maybe for the pros, but for the purpose of illustration, catching like this fine.